# image not showing in a custom uitableviewcell imageview in ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have a custom UITableViewCell then I have a UIImageView inside it. I am able to set its image in iphone and other parts of the app with the same code ..and same customcell ..but I on some parts the image are not showing.
Here is a sample code of the part where it does not show.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    ItemsCell *cell = (ItemsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
//        cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        NSArray *nib;
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemsCell_Ipad" owner:self options:nil];
        }

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = [miscFileNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.artistLabel.text = [miscSizeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        cell.thumbnailImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ext_default.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.thumbnailImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_ext_defaul.png"];

        NSLog(@"%@",cell.thumbnailImgView.image);
    }

    return cell;
}
```

When I log the cell.thumbnailImgView.image it logs the image . but still it doesnt show . In the iPhone its working I have no idea why its not working in iPad.

Comment: Are you passing the correct image name? Check if you have image with this name in your app bundle `ipad_ext_defaul.png`

Comment: Try logging the bounds of cell.thumbnailImgView for the iPad to make sure it doesn't have zero size, or is off screen somewhere.

Comment: use break point and also check your image or image name is proper or not ??

Comment: yes the image name is correct i triple checked it already, it is also added in the copy bundle resources in build phases. I really dont know why it doesnt work I used the same code in another class.

Comment: @rdelmar I tried logging NSLog(@"cell:%f",cell.thumbnailImgView.bounds.origin.x); it says 0.0000 so it means it outside somewhere . what should I do

Comment: im sorry my bad, I changed the log from .bounds to .frame it shows the correct x and y .. hmmm why its not working

Comment: @user1931197 Check your iPad cell XIB for any stray view being added on top of the image view or if the image view has the correct z-index.

Comment: i even tried setting the image of imageview inside the custom cell but still it doesnt appear.

Comment: Did you log the size as well as the origin of the image view? Also, just for a test, reverse which image you show in the if and else parts of the statement to see if the iPad image shows up on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities :

- Just check whether it is loading the ItemsCell_Ipad when you select
  the iPad . means it is loading the right cell .
- Second and most probable is the connections in the custom cell , I
  think  you have forget to make connection with image view in iPad .

Comment: I tried placing a breakpoint its loading ItemsCell_Ipad, The connections are also correct I checked it already and in another class I used this code already and it works . I really dont know why it doesnt work on this one.

Answer (score 0):

First Check "ipad_ext_defaul.png" is in your Resource Folder.(name must be same as you have given in code)
If it is in Resource Folder then delete App from your iPad. Clean your Build and install again.

You will definitely find your Solution.

Good Luck !!!!